# How to deal with massive numbers in C

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption

I am writing an RSA encryption algorithm in C. Im not planning to put it in production anywhere, it is mainly just so I can broaden my understanding of encryption.

How do I deal with the massive numbers that RSA generates? Even when performing decryption with a relatively small private key like 103, I still have the issue of dealing with things like this:

> 67^103 mod 143 = (1.21816096336830017301951805581 x 10^188) mod 143

What is the best way to store a number of that size? Is there any way to do it using standard libraries?
.

Comment: You could implement all big number arithmetic yourself, but it's easier to just use an existing multi-precision library like GMP.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I was thinking I could possibly implement one using arrays to store numbers in base 2^64. I didn't know if that would be practical.

Comment: That would work. Careful with overflow though. You have to implement multiplication, and then division (for modulo). But seriously, just use GMP.

Comment: @mstagg RSA concerns large integers, in your example you show a real number. Here is a case for a big int library, or writing one is educative but not too taxing.

Comment: @Weather Vane Disagree this here `67^103 mod 143` is a case for a big `int` library.   The inputs are all <= 8 bit and everything here is [solvable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33311698/2410359) with quick simple integer math.

Comment: Yeah the way OP has the equation written on the right-hand side seems to indicate he has not yet learned efficient modular exponentiation.  With this efficient ModExp this one could be done with primitives. However, with larger moduli, he will need a bigint library, either homemade or 3rd party.  I agree about GMP. It is very fast. There are 3 main approaches, for example, to multiplication. The school-style long multiplication is the slowest. Multiplication using FFT is the fastest for very large numbers.  Many times faster than most people can code on their own.

Comment: @WDS You mention more efficient modular exponentiation. Could you point me to some resources explaining it?

Comment: @mstagg Wikipedia is not always reliable (particularly on controversial topics) but in this case it is a good place to start.  Specifically under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation you will find psuedocode in the right-to-left binary method that is very fast, yet easy enough to understand.

Comment: @mstagg as a simple example, what is 121 mod 7?  We could trial divide 121 by 7 and find our remainder of 2.  Or we could note that 121 is 11^2.  Then take 11 mod 7 = 4.  Now square the 4 = 16.  And 16 mod 7 = 2.  Same answer, but we never had to work with a 3-digit number.  So methods exist to do modular exponentiation where no partial result will have more than twice as many digits as the modulus itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong approach.  `67^103 mod 143` does not need to first calculate `67^103`.

Calculate the `modulo` in a loop, 1 bit of exponent at a time.

```
uint32_t powmod(uint32_t base, uint32_t expo, uint32_t mod) {

  // % mod need only for the cases expo==0, mod<=1
  uint32_t y = 1u % mod;

  while (expo) {
    if (expo & 1u) {
      y = ((uint64_t) base * y) % mod;
    }
    expo >>= 1u;
    base = ((uint64_t) base * base) % mod;
  }

  return y;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%lu",(unsigned long)  powmod(67, 103, 143));
}
```

Output

```
89
```

Comment: The _trick_ to "deal with the massive numbers that RSA generates" is to not do math the usual way - use short-cuts like the above.

Comment: Oh Oh yes, even done this power exercise before, by treating each bit of the power: not read Q carefully enough, +1.

Comment: @Weather Vane Yes - the whole point of [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is to use computational tricks, if one has the key, to solve a mathematical black box problem that done otherwise are infeasible to calculate by brute force.